# Why does my code never reaches the end when waiting for pipe?

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm trying to use IO.pipe to send messages between processes, but I run into some kind of starvation when I'm waiting for finish messages.

Code: https://carc.in/#/r/12ly

Answer (score 2):

I see one `w_waiter.puts` and 2 times `r_waiter.gets`, that's why it blocks. If I add another `w_waiter.puts` after the first one, it finishes. Is that the problem?

EDIT: I also tried this in Ruby

```
r_producer, w_producer = IO.pipe
r_waiter, w_waiter = IO.pipe

2.times do |i|
  fork do
    puts "in fork #{i}"
    loop do
      message = r_producer.gets.chomp
      sleep 0.1
      puts "#{message} from #{i}"
      break if message == "0"
    end
    puts "sending finish"
    w_waiter.puts "finish"
  end
end

10.times do |i|
  w_producer.puts i + 1
end

2.times do
  w_producer.puts 0
end

2.times { r_waiter.gets }
puts "end of the program"
```

Same result.

I'm not sure using a same pipe for two forked processes work. You should create one pipe for each process.

Alternatively (I don't know what your program is), you could use spawn and channels, as described in the concurrency guide: http://crystal-lang.org/docs/guides/concurrency.html

Comment: But 2 processes are running, both of them should call w_waiter.puts when the loop ends, one is getting stuck and the message "sending finish" is only showed 1 time.

Comment: I just tried this in Ruby and I get the same results:

Comment: I edited the answer with the Ruby code and a brief explanation/guess

Comment: My objective is to use pipe as IPC instead of channels over multiple processes, what should be a better approach? Unix sockets?

Comment: Can you use one pipe for each process?

Comment: That's weird, I reduced to a smaller example, and this works https://carc.in/#/r/12os but this gets stuck https://carc.in/#/r/12oq